# Convex and concave

Tags: functions, derivatives, numerical-methods

My professor at university says that the following function graph is a **convex** graph. So that he also means if the second derivative of a function is negative, the graph is convex. I searched for convex graphs and found the opposite of what he says. So I think my teacher is wrong. But still, I suspect if this is something debatable?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLw7O.png

And he consistently says that the following is a **concave** graph, so that he also means if the second derivative of a function is positive, the graph is concave:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsGK9.png

Comment: Your teacher has the words reversed.  "Convex function" is a very common term.

Comment: @saulspatz Sorry, I meant to say he says the graph is convex. Does this even change anything?

Comment: No, it doesn't change anything.  I just meant there's no room for debate.